# Using Machine Learning to Create Periodic Paths

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, geometry

**Question**: How can I use Machine Learning to predict the right initial conditions $(P_0,V_0)$, given the angles of the triangular table, that will result in periodic paths in the triangular billiard table (no pockets, no friction, no spin, etc.)?

**Context**: I’m tackling a problem known as the Triangle Billiards Problem — and I was hoping to use AI to give me some insight into the problem. Here’s the setup: a billiard table in the shape of a triangle. The ball bounces off the table just as a beam of light reflects off a mirror (i.e., angle of incidence = angle of reflection).

I want to create a neural network that (intelligently?) chooses the initial conditions $(P_0,V_0)$ — initial position and velocity of the billiard ball — that would create a periodic path (i.e., a billiard trajectory that starts repeating on itself). I am hoping this will give me some insight into the triangular billiards problem.

Using VPython, I have already created a simulation of a billiard ball bouncing around in a triangular table, creating periodic (and sometimes non-periodic) paths. I’ve attached an image of my simulation. However, I would now like to bring ML/AI to the picture. I would really appreciate any advice as to how to go about doing this. Should I use reinforcement learning and if so, how should I formulate a reward that distinguishes between periodic and non-periodic paths? What library can I use to model the billiards system above using ML? I’m quite lost on this and I would greatly appreciate any thoughts or suggestions. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Could you explain why you're looking specifically ML for this? If I understand correctly, you want something that, given initial conditions P0 and V0 will tell you whether the path will be periodic or not. Since you have 1) tool at your disposal that can simulate infinite scenarios (because you have complete information about the situation) 2) not a crazy amount of variables (unlike other problems with complete info, like chess), my first reaction is that you would be better off just simulating like 100k situations to create a rough "map" of starting areas + velocities that result in periodic.

Comment: Hi @VladimirBelik thank you for the comment. The thing is, I can indeed try that approach -- for one triangle. But the overall goal is to predict periodic paths in any triangle, given $(P_0,V_0)$. That's why I was thinking of ML.

Comment: Ohhh I see now. So you want the ML to tell you that given not *only* P0 and V0, but also the shape of the triangle, whether it'll be periodic or not?

Comment: @VladimirBelik Right, right. Should I modify the question to add that, or does it suffice the way it is?

Comment: I would add that into your initial question, where you talk about "initial conditions". Something like "given initial conditions P0 and V0, as well the shape/dimension of any triangle". This is an interesting problem. I can't help but feel that there should be some clean mathematical derivation you can do for this, rather than ML (again - since you have complete information and not a crazy number of variables). Have you looked into anything like that?

Comment: @VladimirBelik Haha, this is actually quite the interesting problem! So much so that it's unsolved! That's why I'm hoping to use ML to get some insights into it. OK, I'll add that to the question. I should add that the dimensions of the triangle don't matter -- only the angles.

Comment: Really? Interesting. I found this: https://www.jstor.org/stable/3605605 , so clearly it's not new! But you're sure it's unsolved? Very fun. Alright, let me chew on this a bit. One more thing: Are you able to create a labelled dataset easily, to make this a supervised learning problem? Could you more or less easily simulate 100k or a million scenarios and label each one as "periodic" or "non-periodic"?

Comment: @VladimirBelik Well, since I have a working simulation, I certainly suppose so! Would you like to join me in this project? We can open a chat thread or an email thread or you can star my GitHub repository.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133622/discussion-between-vladimir-belik-and-rb3652).

Comment: @VladimirBelik OK, I'm in the chat room.